# VueJs Component's Prop-Dependent Computed Property Not Reactive to Array of Objects Prop Changes

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-reactivity, vue-props

### Background

I have a Vue component, `question-panel`, which accepts a prop `questions`, which is an array of objects and has variable length.

In the `<template>...</template>`, there are some HTML elements to display information of the computed `question` object, such as `question.name`, `question.score`, etc.

There are also two buttons which calls `previousQuestion()` and `nextQuestion()` when clicked.

### Issue

According to Vue.js devtools, the prop `questions` does bind and react to changes from parent.

However, the computed `question` does not get recalculated even after prop `questions` changes.

On the other hand, it does get recalculated when `questionIndex` changes.

How should I workaround this behavior? Is this implementation against Vue's principle?

### Segment of QuestionPanel.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    questions: Array,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      questionIndex: 0,
    };
  },

  computed: {
    question: function () {
      return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
    },
  },

  methods: {
    previousQuestion() {
      if (this.questionIndex > 0) {
        this.questionIndex--;
        this.$emit("questionChanged", this.question);
      }
    },
    nextQuestion() {
      if (this.questionIndex < this.questions.length - 1) {
        this.questionIndex++;
        this.$emit("questionChanged", this.question);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

### Segment of Parent.Vue

```
<paper-panel
  @questionsArrived="Object.assign(questions, $event)"
></paper-panel>

<question-panel
  :questions="questions"
></question-panel>
```

### Vue.js Devtools Screen

[Computed `question` still sits at its default state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa4Wk.png)

Comment: Did you try using `@watch`, [it](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) might help?

Comment: How are you setting the new values of the array question on the parent?

Comment: How do you change the prop questions from the parent? Some changes may not be reactive

Comment: @yuri @Oliver `:questions="questionsInParent"`, `questionsInParent` is set like so: `<another-component @questionsArrived="Object.assign(questionsInParent, $event)>...</another-component>`

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a watcher and solve it but the problem is on the reactivity of the `question` prop.

`Object.assign` is not performing a deep copy of your array, I suggest you try the following:

`Object.assign({}, questionsInParent, $event)`

instead of

`Object.assign(questionsInParent, $event)`

Why? Because Object.assign does a shallow copy of the keys and values.
Your prop is an array of objects, so when you are doing Object.assign you are coping only the reference of every object inside your array, so it is really not detecting any changes as the reference may be still the same.

---

This topic is covered in:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

you can also take a look on how object assign produces copies:

[Object.assign - MDN Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

and finally:

[How to clone objects on javascript](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/)

Comment: I tried watching the `questions` prop in my child component but Vue does not detect changes despite seeing from devtools the `questions` prop does indeed change.

Comment: My originally use of `Object.assign` actually causes the prop to change, but when using `@questionsArrived="questions = Object.assign({}, questions, $event)"` it does not.